# Artificial neural network with Ruby

Tags: ruby, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to use some artificial neural network with Ruby, I tried few gems (ruby-fann, Ai4r) and both of them when I run trained network on some test inputs always returns me same thing [1.0, 1.0], but in training data all outputs are around 100. I have 10 input neurons, and 2 output. I tried different network configurations, desire error, with different number of layers and different number of neurons. While training ruby-fann's NN I get this:

```
1. Current error: 10034.23571597 Bit fail: 1938
100. Current error: 9937.62571597 Bit fail: 1938
```

After that all errors and fails are the same. Here is my code:

```
inputs_to_learn = []
outputs_to_learn = []
some cycle:
    inputs_to_learn.push([i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9,i10,])
    outputs_to_learn.push([o1, o2])
train = RubyFann::TrainData.new(:inputs=>inputs_to_learn, :desired_outputs=>outputs_to_learn)
fann = RubyFann::Standard.new(:num_inputs=>10, :hidden_neurons=>[30, 30, 30, 30], :num_outputs=>2) 
fann.train_on_data(train, 1000, 100, 0.5)
result = fann.run([100, 100, 95, 105, 95, 105, 95, 105, 95, 105])
```

So the question is, why do I get 1.0 if train data is 100 times bigger numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very many options available when building a neural network. One important choice is the transfer function applied to the total of all inputs times weights on each neuron. This may also be called the activation function.

This affects you mainly on the output layer. For your networks, values of 100 are not possible in the output, so the network cannot properly learn them.

It is quite common to see networks using the logistic function (or sigmoid), which always outputs between 0.0 and 1.0. With some NN libraries, that might be the only choice you have.

You have two basic choices to improve the convergence of your network here:

1) Read the documentation for the library you are using, and see if it is possible to have a linear output layer (i.e. no transfer function is applied). This could be a good choice for other reasons if you are trying to create a regression model on a continuous variable.

2) Scale your output variable to fit the available output range of 0.0..1.0. You will need to map your training data to this range, and then reverse that mapping when interpreting the output, using the network for new input data.

If I remember correctly FANN, and thus ruby-fann, has quite limited choices when it comes to types of neuron, and other features of modern NNs (e.g. regularisation, various "clever" batch learning tricks etc). I thought that there might be none - in which case your only choice would be to scale the training targets to fit in range `0..1`. However, from your comment I can see that [there are a few methods available to set activation functions](http://ruby-fann.rubyforge.org/RubyFann/Standard.html#method-i-set_activation_function).

For best performance, ideally you should also scale the inputs, based on your training data. Typically you normalise them to have mean 0.0, standard deviation 1.0 on the training set (and use same offsets and multipliers for all inputs from that point forward), although limiting range to 0.0..1.0 or -1.0..1.0 is pretty common too.

Comment: An aside: I'm sad to say that NN libraries in Ruby are not up to much. If learning NNs is a priority you may find switching to Python, using Scikit-Learn or Lasagne/no-learn as libraries will ultimately give you much more flexibility and access to better cutting-edge techniques.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, It helped me to find a "direction", turned out there is a methods in ruby-fann class, with which it is possible to set "activation function" for neurons. Methods are like set_activation_function_output(:linear) for output neurons and set_activation_function_hidden(:linear) for hidden ones. (http://ruby-fann.rubyforge.org/RubyFann/Standard.html)

Comment: I didn't know that. You will want to keep non-linear neurons in the hidden layers, it is generally just the output layer that should be linear for some types of problem.